# About the use of non-defining participles

Tags: participles

Is it me, or is the use of the participles questionable in the following sentences?

(1) [ injuring ]

*The FBI is investigating the shooting of a military helicopter during a training mission this week in northern Virginia, **injuring** one crew member who was aboard, officials said Wednesday.*

I know the logical subject of "injuring" is "the shooting," which is the object of the verb "investigate" in the main clause. Is it acceptable to use a non-defining participle in this way, which might cause the confusion that it was FBI, the subject, that caused the injury?

I think it would make more sense to just drop the comma before "injuring," as in:

The FBI is investigating the bombing of a building injuring at least 100 people.

---

(2) [ causing ]

*The initial findings of the investigation show that the helicopter was struck by a bullet, **causing** some damage to the aircraft, though it landed safely, the Air Force said.*

Compared to the first one, this is more acceptable. Right?

---

The sentences are from a news report:
https://www.1011now.com/2020/08/12/fbi-investigates-shooting-of-military-helicopter-in-virginia/?fbclid=IwAR04HyaQqbcm6zBJP4xwFyPLtgKtUgGe6jZdteIVWyN0Z1aCyfwNIkU4lCk

Comment: I agree about the first sentence. The simplest fix might be to end it on "... northern Virginia, officials said.", and start a new sentence: "The shooting injured one of the crew." The second sentence is alright, but why not use "which caused..."?

Comment: Thanks. Very clear and helpful. @Jack O'Flaherty